# IzPack equivalent to NSIS ReadCustomerData?

Tags: java, installation, nsis, izpack

I want to personalize (customize, preconfigure etc) each copy of the installer I give out. But, of course, I do not want to recompile the installer every time. 
NSIS has a [solution](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) where you append the data to the executable. Can you suggest a solution with IzPack?

One idea I had, is to add data post installation to the installer JAR file, but I can't figure where and how to read it...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A JAR stores its headers at the end of the file, this means your custom data must be added to the beginning of the file (A combined GIF and JAR is known as a GIFAR and has been used for some exploits in the past, so just make sure you don't start your custom data with something that looks like a GIF (or other image format) header to avoid AV false positives)

Comment: OK. But how would IzPack would use such data? Is there an API to extract this data while installing the software?

Comment: @Lurker76: I don't know anything about IzPack, but it does support custom actions: http://izpack.org/documentation/custom-actions.html Without knowing what this custom data is for, it is hard to know if it can be done with custom actions...

Comment: Have you tried storing this data in the META_INF/Manifest file ?